# How to get JSON data from 100 different but similar URL

Tags: json, swift, nsurl

So the website of API in which I am going to request can only handle 50 items per request (I need the whole data, which is 5001 by the way) is there any way to make a URL with special characters that can enable parsing from 101 different (but similar) URL? (the differences are in the back of each URL, the skip number needs to be changed and thats all)(it says cannot compile value of '(String: Int)' into an expected argument type String

```
func fetchDataForNearbyStops(completionHandler : ([Nearby]?, String?) -> ()){

    let requestURLStr = "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusStops?$skip="
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: requestURLStr)
        let reqNum : Int = 0
        let reqURLStr = requestURLStr + (String: reqNum)
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = reqURL
    request.HTTPMethod = Cara
    request.addValue(AccKey, forHTTPHeaderField: AccKeyField)
    request.addValue(UniqueUID, forHTTPHeaderField: UniqueUIDField)
    request.addValue(CustomHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: CustomHeaderField)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        do {
        if let JSONDataArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? [AnyObject] {
            print(JSONDataArray)
            }
        } catch {
        }
        }
        task.resume()
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        completionHandler(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: how have you tried to modify the URL string so far ? what went wrong ?

Comment: I tried to make the URL as a string and the numbers as an int which can be added on and on but I can't seem to get it working @Wain

Comment: show that code, include the compile / runtime error

Comment: let requestURLStr = "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusStops?$skip="
            let reqNum : Int = 0
            let reqURLStr = requestURLStr + (String: reqNum) it says cannot compile value of (String: Int) into an expected argument type String

Comment: Hello Ronald! Please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Thank you!

Comment: oops okay thanks for the suggestion @EricD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very close, you basically just put a bracket in the wrong place...

```
let requestURLStr = "datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusStops?$skip=";
let reqNum : Int = 0

let reqURLStr = requestURLStr + String(reqNum)
```

you need to create a `String` instance with the number. You should then use 2 functions, 1 to control how many pages to request and one to send the request:

```
func sendRequests() {
    for page in 0...10 {
        sendPageRequest(page)
    }
}

func sendPageRequest(page: Int) {
    let requestURLStr = "datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusStops?$skip=";
    let reqURLStr = requestURLStr + String(page)

    ...
```

Comment: Can you give me more information how to make the integer add value itself while its writing into the coredata? thank you

Comment: you mean how to create multiple URLs? you should be adding the `reqNum` as a parameter on a func and calling that func multiple times. though also, that func should be adding the requests to a queue so you only execute a few at a time (or configure the session to limit requests to the host)

Comment: yea I am pointing towards it like how to get multiple data from different URL for a single function... So sorry but I am still quite new to swift can you show me how to do it? Considering the whole function is there already... Thanks anyway @Wain

Comment: you should use multiple functions, one to control how many requests and one to make the request

Comment: Thank you for the response :)